# SPSS Comparing means between groups

Tags: spss, sample-size

I am currently working on a project about the performance of Himalayan mountaineering teams. I want to compare differences between these teams on the basis of the mountain they attempt to conquer *and* the season they try to do so. I have created a database in SPSS with a total of 27,000 individual summiting bids, each varying in mountain (e.g. Mt Everest, Annapurna, Lhotse etc.) and climbing season.

The problem is, some of these mountain * season combinations only count 5 cases, whereas others count up to 5,000 unique cases. For example, the Mount Everest has been attempted over 8,000 in the spring season alone, whereas the Annapurna has only been attempted 5 times in the summer season. Of course, I can not compare the performance outcomes (success of expedition) between the two groups.

What I can't figure out is which test I should run in SPSS to pick out the mountain * season combinations that do not have enough statistical significance to keep in the analysis, due to the lack of cases they have. It is no problem to delete them.  Help!